# Net Core 2 Serilog inject from Console App to Webhost

Tags: c#, startup, serilog, .net-core-2.0

I would like to know how to manage and best way to bring Serilog instance from a console app to a StartUp class that configures a webhost.

Scenario:

I ve got a Main class from a console app where I configure a logger (serilog). 
Namespace 1

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime Date = new DateTime.Now;
           Log.Logger = = new LoggerConfiguration()
         .MinimumLevel.Debug()
         .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
         .Enrich.FromLogContext()
         .WriteTo.Console()
         .WriteTo.File($"Log-Startup-{Date}.txt", rollingInterval: 
RollingInterval.Day, outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff 
zzz}")
         .CreateLogger();

[...]

`StaticLauncherClass.Launch(args, config, Log.Logger)`;
```

Notice after this I'm just doing a call to static class method and I pass the Logger.

Static class is supposed to configure a Webhost as typical webhost app in net core 2. Launch Method does something like.  Namespace2

```
      public static IConfiguration Config { get; private set; }


public static void Launch(string[] args, IConfigurationSection config, 
ILogger logger)
        {
            Log.Logger = logger;
            Config = config;
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }


      public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Information("Starting web host");
  Serilog.ILogger _logger = Log.Logger;
            try
            {
                return CreateWebhostBuilder(args)
                        // Use Serilog
                        // Evitar inicio de hospedaje
                        .UseSerilog()
                        .UseSetting(WebHostDefaults.PreventHostingStartupKey, 
"true")
                    .ConfigureServices(svc =>
{
    svc.AddSingleton(_logger);
})
                        .UseStartup<Startup>();
            }
[...]
}
```

In same class, finally CreateWebhostBuilder(args) configure webhost

```
 var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
           .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new 
AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                    if (appAssembly != null)
                    {
                        config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
                    }
                }

                if (args != null)
                {
                    config.AddCommandLine(args);
                }
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                // Add settings to bootstrap EF config.
            })

            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = 
context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            });


    return builder;
```

And then my question si how with this scenario I can **use my Logger in Startup used class. My intention is to globalize logger the best and easier way posible. What solutions you purpose?**

```
 internal class Startup {
???
???
 public Startup(IConfiguration config, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {       
        ???
    }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Startup");
        Log.Information("Startup: Configure services");
    }
}
```

Startup class is writing Console.WriteLine content but does not write Log.Information content.
Edit: Actual status, bring service to Startup but does not apply configuration provided to log in file. I think it acts just by default.

Comment: It seems to me that, in your scenario, is totally advisable to just use the static `Serilog.Log.Logger` property. I do not see any advantage in using a scoped instance inside your `Program` class.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma that is true. I ve changed code. But how could I pass (and Log) from startup class?

Comment: Now that you have the static instance you can just use `Log.Info()` (and the other methods) from your startup class

Comment: The point is that I am doing Log.Information("Startup: Configure services"); from ConfigureServices method and it does not write anything in the console or file and I dont know what I am missing.

Comment: Are you sure your `ConfigureServices` method is ever called? Did you try to put a brakepoint inside it?

Comment: Yes. And If I do Console.WriteLine("Blah blah") inside ConfigureServices it is working as normal. I have using Serilog; also.. You have some idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Not really. Can you update your question with your changes? It still uses the old logger instance.

Comment: I have updated the post with actual code. Startup class is writing Console.WriteLine content but does not write Log.Information content

Comment: In your post you didn't add all the information needed to find your issue, but from the github repository you posted earlier is **clear** that you are executing `Log.CloseAndFlush();` right after creating the WebHostBuilder (which, of course, will close the current logger immediatly). That's the reason you do not see any log after. Please add the complete code to your question.

Comment: Actually you found my error. Thanks. I will post the entire solution for this scenario soon. Thank you very much since I was a bit ofuscated with it trying to understand what was happening and I had forget that declaration coming from a snippet I took from docs.. Really thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can register your logger in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()

            ...

            .UseIISIntegration()
            .ConfigureServices(servicesCollection =>
            {
                servicesCollection.AddSingleton<Serilog.ILogger>(logger);              
            })
            .UseDefaultServiceProvider((context, options) =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = 
context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment();
            });
```